# Converting curl api call to httparty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, httparty

I am fairly new to Httparty and I would like to do user auth through httparty. The command in curl works.

```
curl --data "username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&token=132321212" 'https://hekki.isks.com/api/userauth'
```

I can't quite convert that into httparty. I have this so far.

```
response = HTTParty.post("https://hekki.isks.com/api/userauth", 
      :username => "hello",
      :password => "no",
      :token => 132321212,
      :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' } )
```

Comment: why are you using json content-type when your example is not posting json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
response = HTTParty.post("https://hekki.isks.com/api/userauth",
                         :body=> { 
                                    :username => "hello",
                                    :password => "no",
                                    :token => 132321212 
                                  } )
```